# "Didn't understand relationship 'Histories' in FROM part of query call." When query Seller History from Seller

Tags: apex, query, database

I am getting an script-thrown exception when query Seller History from Seller. Here is my apex class:

```
public without sharing class MainLayoutController {
    public static SObject getAllRelatedListRecords(String objectApiName, String recordId, List<String> lsChildObjectName) {
        try {
            if(objectApiName != null && recordId != null && lsChildObjectName.size() > 0) {
                String query = 'SELECT Id';
                for (String childObjectName : lsChildObjectName) {
                        query += ' ,(SELECT Id FROM ' + childObjectName + ')';
                }
                query += ' FROM ' + objectApiName + ' WHERE Id = :recordId';
                System.debug(query);
                SObject result = Database.query(query);
                return result;
            } 
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Execute Anonymous:

```
SObject a = MainLayoutController.getAllRelatedListRecords('Seller', '0q65j0000000027AAA' , new List<String>{'Histories'});
System.debug(a);
```

When I ran this method in Execute Anonymuous like above, I got the error `Didn't understand relationship 'Histories' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."`

However, When I tried to pass the query string and execute without calling apex class, it worked.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id ,(SELECT Id FROM Histories) FROM Seller WHERE Id = \'0q65j0000000027AAA\'';
SObject a = Database.query(query);
System.debug(a); // It worked and returned value
```

Debug:

```
a|{"Id":"0q65j0000000027AAA","Histories":[{"SellerId":"0q65j0000000027AAA","Id":"0175j0000IfyB1ZAQU"}]}|
```

I don't understand why my apex class does not work. Please help to find the root cause. Thank you!

Comment: This is typically because the contextual user does not have permissions to read the required object and/or field.

Comment: @PhilW, but both the codes are executed via anonymous apex, wouldn't it run on the same context?

Comment: Fair point, though anonymous apex statements run in user mode, while the Apex called by it will run in system mode. Honestly, I would have expected the opposite behaviour to what you are stating. Very strange. I wait for someone else to respond and remedy my ignorance.

Comment: I am AFK, and this may sound silly, but are you sure you can access `Id` on the History object? Normally the `Id` referenced is called SomeObjectNameId...

Comment: Is the query you tried the one that was logged in the first call? Or did you hand re-write the query? If its not from the debug log message I'd pull that out and make sure it's my expected query.

Comment: @acrosman I copied this query from `System.debug(query);` in the Apex class, it worked. But it didn't work when calling the apex class inside execute anonymuous.

Comment: @PhilW Strangely that I can query in Query Editor and Execute Anonymous directly. But I couldn't use it inside Apex. I couldn't check whether I'm possible to access Id in Seller History because it didn't appear in the list of Standard Objects

Comment: For standard objects, I found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_associated_objects_history.htm) which does not list `Id`.